# How do you create slidedown effects like this?

Tags: javascript, css

check this out 
http://heroku.com/

How do you created stuff like this?(referring to the slidedown) Do you have mouseover events for javascript or is it all css? Cud someone please give a basic outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this jQuery accordion widget. It has a mouseover effect, like the one on heroku.com

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#mouseover

Comment: they do not even use ui or a plugin

Comment: Loading an entire library for one effect seems like a bad idea.

Comment: What is another 70K on a web page? My phone provider's homepage is 
0.5MB when I load it on my phone...

Comment: A lot of websites use jquery & jquery ui, including stackoverflow, so the chances that the user will have to load the library are greatly reduced. That's why linking to the google api jquery library is so popular.

Answer (score 1):

Simple jQuery.
View the source to see how

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you don't need to load the entire jQuery library.
[A simple div slide down JS script](http://djpate.com/2009/02/22/a-simple-div-slide-down-js-script/)

```
function doSlide(id){
    timeToSlide = 50; // in milliseconds
    obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if(obj.style.display == "none"){ // if it's allready hidden we slide it down
       obj.style.visibility = "hidden";
       obj.style.display = "block";
       height = obj.offsetHeight;
       obj.style.height="0px";
       obj.style.visibility = "visible";
       slideDown(obj,0,height,Math.ceil(height/timeToSlide));
    } else {
       slideUp(obj,Math.ceil(obj.offsetHeight/timeToSlide),obj.offsetHeight);
    }
}

function slideDown(obj,offset,full,px){
    if(offset < full){
       obj.style.height = offset+"px";
       offset=offset+px;
       setTimeout((function(){slideDown(obj,offset,full,px);}),1);
    } else {
       obj.style.height = full+"px"; //If the data inside is updated on runtime you can use auto instead...
    }
}

function slideUp(obj,px,full){
   if((obj.offsetHeight-px) > 0){
      obj.style.height = obj.offsetHeight-px+"px";
      setTimeout((function(){slideUp(obj,px,full);}),1);
   } else {
      obj.style.height=full+"px"; // we reset the height if we were to slide it back down
      obj.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```